# HTML Video control with rich APIs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, html

I need to have a **video** control in HTML with rich and comprehensive APIs. I need some features like playing and pausing and navigating through a video "Go to specific hour/minute".
Also I look forward extra features like search and pairing with TVs.
I know there are some Jquery plugins and HTML5 video tag.

Any recommendations please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a video control videojs that comes with plugins similar to what I need [VideoJs](http://videojs.com)